# How do I stream JSON objects from ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I'm trying to stream JSON objects from an ExpressJS / Node backend API to a frontend site.

I do not want to use Sockets.IO for various reasons. As I understand it, the native streaming libraries should support streaming objects, it appears that just Express is complicating this.

My frontend code seams straight forward. I use Fetch to get my target URL, get a read stream from the response object, and set that read stream to objectMode: true.

Frontend Example:

```
    async function () {

      let url = "myurl";

      let response = await fetch( url, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        wtihCredentials: 'include'
      }

      const reader = response.body.getReader({objectMode: true });

      // Where things are a bit ambiguous
      let x = true;
      while (x) {
        const {done, value} = reader.read()
        if (done) { break; }

        // do something with value ( I push it to an array )

      }      
}
```

Backend Bode Example ( fails because of I cannot change the stream to objectMode )

```
router.get('/', (request, response) => {

  response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' });

  MongoDB.connection.db.collection('myCollection').find({}).forEach( (i) => {
    response.write(i);
  }).then( () => {
    response.end()
  })
})
```

Now my problem is that there does not appear to be anyway to change the ExpressJS write stream to objectMode: true. To my dismay, the ExpressJS documentation doesn't even acknoledge the existence of the write() function on the response object: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

How do I change this over to objectMode: true ?

conversely, I tried to work with the writeStream as a string. The problem that I run into is that when the send buffer fills up, it does it by characters, not by the object. These means that at some point invalid JSON is passed to requester.

A suggested solution that I run into often is that I could read all of the chunks on the client and assemble valid JSON. This defeats the purpose of streaming, so Im trying to find a better way.

For what I believe is the same problem, I cannot figure out how to talk directly to the write stream object from the express code so I am unable to use the native writeStream operation writable.length in order to manually check to see if there is space for the entire JSON object as a string. This is preventing me from using stringified JSON with new line terminators.

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_writablelength

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_writableobjectmode

Could someone set me straight? I am working with 100k + records in my Mongo database, I really need partical page loading to work so that the users can start picking through the data.

Comment: I don't know if it's doable, but I guess it's bad idea to do it, instead use web sockets, socket.io is very easy to implement and integrate with expressjs.

Comment: All the data relevent to one request is sent to client in single response object. Since you JSON object is too big and you cannot use sockets therefore I will advise you to send multiple AJAX requests from client. You can decide how much data to send in response of single AJAX request. Since request is AJAX (or you can use any other request of same type), web page will not reload and your front end will receive data as if it is coming as a stream. Since you records are 100k + therefore it's good to send AJAX requests in a timely manner. Like 10 requests, again 10 after response of first 10.

Comment: The answer will depend on whether the API shall reply with valid JSON, or if you're in control of both FE and BE and the only goal is to stream the data with minimum computational overhead? Personally, I would recommend conforming to the JSON standard.

Answer (score 1):

Quite some time has passed but I'll answer this anyways for all those that come across this in the future.

You don't need to use objectMode: true. You should stream as text, because that's what JSON is - text, just in a format that can be parsed. You don't need to be afraid of JSON parsing and stringifying, as it's an important and natural part of using Javascript and transferring data.

You correctly identified that the chunks you receive on the frontend are not guaranteed to correspond to the exact JSON you send from the frontend. To get around this, we can use a delimiter like the newline character \n to separate valid chunks of stringified JSON. When you call `JSON.stringify()`, any newline characters in your JSON are escaped so that they won't mess with the delimiter. On the frontend, we will use a buffer to hold any WIP string that isn't ready to be parsed yet.

On the server:

```
for await (const obj of objects){ // Replace with however you get your objects
  const asString = `${JSON.stringify(obj)}\n`;
  res.write(asString);
}
```

On the client:

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
          // your settings
        });
        if (!response.ok || !response.body) {
          throw response.statusText;
        }
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder();

        let buffer = ``;
        while (true) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
          const { done, value } = await reader.read();
          if (done) break;

          buffer += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });

          const boundary = buffer.lastIndexOf(`\n`);
          if (boundary !== -1) {
            const completeData = buffer.substring(0, boundary);
            buffer = buffer.substring(boundary + 1);

            completeData.split(`\n`).forEach(chunk => {
              if (chunk) {
                try {
                  const jsonObj = JSON.parse(chunk);
                  // Yay! Do what you want with your JSON here!
                } catch (e) {
                  console.error(`Error parsing JSON:`, e);
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
```